# Describing delivery, route, travel, distance, duration?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, translation

I found some phrases in dictionaries but I do not know **if these words/phrases are really used by native speakers**. Sometimes my dictionaries make me choose the wrong word and I don't have a feeling for what is common.

I selected the best but want to ask native speakers if this is **valid usage** and **common/often used** - please help with phrases.

**Can I use such phrases/words:**

1. *route* or *directions* (as way between two points)?
2. *route duration time* or *route duration* (as time to travel between two points)?
3. *route distance* (as distance to travel between two points)?
4. *directions map* (as map between two points)?

**Can I use same the phrase/words to describe delivery** (i.e. takeaway food):

1. *delivery route* (as way between two points)?
2. *delivery duration time* or *route duration* (as time to travel between two points)?
3. *delivery distance* (as distance to travel between two points)?
4. *maximum delivery time* or *maximum delivery duration*?
5. *maximum delivery distance*?
6. *price depends on delivery distance*?
7. *price depends on delivery time* or *price depends on delivery duration* (not sure if I could use *duration* in place of *time*)?
8. *delivery hours* (when delivery is possible similar to a store's hours)?

**Which is better:**

1. *delivery duration* or *route duration* (as time of travel between points)?
2. *delivery distance* or *route distance*  (as distance of travel between points)?

---

It is a little long but I want to give full context. You could copy the whole context and comment if you wish to do so or just point out what is wrong/good.

Comment: All those phrases are business-speak. What do you want these phrases for? A business? They all seem reasonably clear and understandable, but they're not sentences. You'll have to put them into sentences that you want to use, provide a context, and ask a reasonable question.

Comment: I could put them all into sentences but still **not feel what is common use**. I want use them also without sentences like labels. Yes it is related to travel and delivery. I do not what use business/technical slang always prefer to use **common communicative language**. Should I make separate question with sentences with full context. This question could be quite useful since this currently it is often used.

Comment: My experience with business-speak like this is that it's more common than "common communicative language", which I'll assume means "the language native speakers use when they have conversations". The writers of this type of information like to use as few words as possible & as many phrases found in similar explanations from other companies. That makes sense because it leads to standard phrases, but that doesn't always mean standard meanings. Looking at [explanations of shipping policies](http://snurl.com/26ximny) may help.

Comment: Hi Chameleon. One of the requirements of questions on this site is that there is a single specific, answerable question posted. Unfortunately you're asking many things at once, and none of them is particularly fleshed out. So unfortunately I'm going to have to close this as Not A Real Question. If you'd like to edit this question to ask a single question, you're welcome to do so and @ message me to request reopening. Thanks!

Comment: @WendiKidd Not really understand of use of 12 separated questions split from context - it good for yes/no but nor for language I think. Can you explain how do you imagine split of this question as you suggested - to make good questions and answers?

Comment: @Chameleon: There's some help for how to write good questions on the FAQ: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask, but in summary, your question needs to be **specific**. For example you can ask "How would a native speaker ask how to get from A to B / Would a native speaker ask 'what is the best route to X', or 'can you give me directions to X'" and that question would be fine. Asking lists of questions within a single question does not fit the Stack Exchange format.

Comment: @Matt For me question is about travel/delivery usage. It is not separate questions whatever each person can have different opinion if it question or not. **Usability** conquers **Correctness**, **Purity**, **Details** or **Rules** - that is important here too. I can make ten question but this one will much better for all people using ELL. I can follow the best rules but I do not ask ten questions coming for rules since not usable for me :) **Usability** conquers **rules** :) All has reasons also rules should have - it could be **usability** or **fancy**.

Answer (score 1):

1) route or directions (as way between two points)? - route is better, directions mean more like the *instructions* from A to B.

2) Duration of travel, or more informally - travel time

3) Distance of travel, or more informally - travel distance

4) I don't quite know what you mean.

---

1) Delivery route

2) Delivery time

3) Delivery distance

4) Maximum delivery time

5) Maximum delivery radius (most takeaways go by radii rather than distance)

6/7) Delivery cost/charges relative to delivery distance/time.

8) Delivery hours

---

Would use delivery time and delivery distance.

Comment: ad4. directions map - mean something like this (http://goo.gl/maps/IxyZG)

Comment: ad5. maximum delivery radius - currently it is changing radius is not good since river/traffic jams - geo service allow simply calculate distance/duration i.e. Google Map.

Answer (score 1):

***Route*** or ***directions***

One might ask for *directions*:

> Could you give me directions to the movie theater?

One might wonder about the *route*:

> Is this the best *route* to the theater?  It might be faster to take Main St.

Although a typical informal conversation would probably just use *way* instead of *route*

> Is this the best *way* to the theater?  It might be faster to take Main St.

***Route duration time*** is not typical.

A native would probably just say "How long will it take to get there?"

A pilot might talk about *time en route* or ETE (Estimated Time En route)

***Route distance***

A native would probably just say, "How far is it?" or "How many miles is it?"

***Delivery route***

The term *delivery route* is typically used to describe the usual path a delivery truck takes when making its rounds.

If you are calling for delivery of take-out food or are the delivery person asking for directions to the caller's home, you'd probably just ask, "Can you give me directions to your house?"

***Delivery distance***, ***maximum delivery distance***

Restaurants that deliver usually speak in terms of a delivery area.  The area could be defined by a set of intersecting roads:

> We deliver as far north as Route 60, as far south as Route 101, east to Power Rd and west to Main st.

Sometimes they will also just talk about a delivery radius:

> We deliver up to 10 miles.

***Maximum delivery time***

Not sure if you are intending to mean you define your delivery area in terms of travel time instead of distance or that you guarantee delivery in "30 minutes or less"

> Our delivery charge is $0.50 / mile
>
> *Delivery hours* is fine. Especially when the hours are quoted right afterward:
>
> > Delivery Hours:  9AM - 10PM.

***Delivery duration*** or ***route duration***, ***delivery distance*** or ***route distance***

Don't use *route* in either case.  More context is needed to understand whether you could replace *duration* with *time* without causing confusion.  (Delivery time could reasonably be 28 minutes in the right context, but it could also be 7:35pm in a different context).

Comment: Restaurants usually speak in terms of delivery area, radius but it is changing after improvement geolocation i.e. Google Maps - now you could calculate enough accurate distance or duration of delivery. You could say that you could delivery if duration time will shorter than 30 minutes (it will depend on day of week/time of day (indirectly traffic jams). It is much easier customer not need study radius or duration - you just get answer yes or no if delivery possible.

Comment: _Maximum delivery time_ == in this context it is time to travel delivery distance at specific/day of week/hour of day. It looks that is wrong name - since _maximum delivery time_ is more related to "guarantee delivery in 30 minutes" than to predicted travel duration. it looks that _maximum delivery time_  == food preparation time + delivery time. Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: I will use phrase with more context _delivery duration_ conquers _route duration_ as you said - thank you for whole suggestions was very good - I am not native speaker and many times was bound with dictionaries faults.

Comment: @Chameleon- As a consumer I would boycott any restaurant that changed its mind about whether it could deliver to me or not based on variables that were not in my control (i.e., the traffic). So while theoretically possible to compute whether a delivery could be made to my address in 30 minutes I hope you aren't seriously considering employing such a model for an actual restaurant.  You could provide an estimated delivery time based on your algorithm and then let the customer decide whether wanted to wait or not.  But don't decide for them, that will just make them mad.